# Package upload test failing - how to debug?

Tags: unit-test, community

I am trying to upload an unmanaged package to SalesForce - but it keeps failing due to tests failing.

All my tests run fine in my org, I do not have any SeeAllData, and I have over 90% code coverage.

I can view which tests are failing, the line number and failure description (like assert failed) but I want to know if I can access a more detailed log? At the moment one of my test classes is failing, but it calls a lot of other classes.

Comment: What do you mean "Upload to salesforce" Are you installing into an org or are you uploading to create the published version? Also, what are the failure messages? If we at least start with as much information as your are looking at then we can help you better, otherwise any answer would be a guess.

Comment: Sorry, @Eric - my package is failing when 'publishing' the package I have made in my org to SalesForce. The errors are test failures, as I stated. What I am really trying to ask is - is there a debug log for tests executed during package upload?